# Stretching cell height according to content using Auto Layout

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` within a `UIView` - The Tableview is dynamically populated - how do I stretch the height of the tableview and parent view according to the dynamic content?

Is it possible using auto-layout?